# Showing two group are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that the group $$g=\langle a,b \mid a^2 ba^{-1}b,a^4,b^2\rangle$$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}= \langle x \mid x^2\rangle$.

This is my working out $$a^2ba^{-1}b=e$$ $$\to a^2=b^{-1}ab^{-1}$$ $$\to a^2=bab$$ $$\to e=a^4=(bab)(bab)$$

Then why does this last go to $bab^2ab=e$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
a^2ba^{-1}b = e \tag{1}\\
a^4 = e \tag{2}\\
b^2 = e \tag{3}
\end{align}

Using $(3)$:
\begin{align}
a^2ba^{-1}b = e \implies a^2ba^{-1} = b \implies a^2 = bab^{-1} \tag{4}
\end{align}
By $(2)$, then
\begin{equation}
e = a^4 \overset{(4)}= (bab^{-1})(bab^{-1}) = ba^2b^{-1} \overset{(4)}{=} b(bab^{-1})b^{-1} = b^2ab^{-2} = a \, .
\end{equation}
In the last step we use $(3)$, realising that $b^2 = e \implies b^{-2} = e$. Then the group reduces to $ g = \langle b \mid b^2\rangle$ as required.

Comment: $a^2$ should be equal to bab

Comment: Take $a^2ba^{-1} = b$ then multiply both sides by $ab^{-1}$

Comment: @Aljabra Since $b^2 = e$, then $b^{-1} = b$, so $a^2 = bab^{-1} = bab$.  Both are correct.

Comment: @James Nice proof +1.  I changed the formatting a bit: if you don't like it feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: @spamIam with this sort of question, how do you know where to start and where to go?

Comment: @Aljabra There really is no general method.  In this case, I would notice that one of the generators already satisfied the condition $b^2 = e$, so I would try to prove that the other generator is trivial, just as James did.  However, in general there is no algorithm to solve this problem: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups).

Comment: @spamIam ok. In the answer above, we have $a=e$. does that not mean that it also satisfies the condition?

Comment: @Aljabra When you write a presentation for a group, it means that the generators satisfy only the relations given, and any relations that can be deduced from them.  So while $a$ does satisfy $a^2 = e$, this is not a minimal relation.  Namely, $a = e$ implies $a^2 = e$ but $a^2 = e$ does not imply $a = e$, since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \langle x \mid x^2 = e \rangle$ provides a counterexample.  [See here for more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Definition).

Comment: @spamIam ok thanks